# linux command line, password protect file using script

Tags: linux, command-line, zip

really new to linux scripting so i figured i would ask rather than waste time pulling my hair out.

i have a simple script that backs up the contents of a folder on my linux box and moves it to S3 storage, i would like this script to create a zip file and password protect it without any intervention from me.

i got it down to

```
zip myarchive.zip /var/www/* -e
```

but cannot work out where i should put the password to stop it prompting me.

thanks
kris

Comment: Not directly answering your question: have you considered using gpg to encrypt the file with your public key?  That way, you don't need the secret on the machine you're backing up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing that is a security risk as it means your password will be written in cleartext in your script.

For this reason, `zip` refuses to work that way. It wants the input from the keyboard, not your script or a file.

<s>I'm not aware of a workaround.</s>

On the other hand, at least the `zip` in my Ubuntu distribution offers a `-P password` option which, I think, allows you to enter the password right on the command line. The documentation surrounds this option with the appropriate warnings.

Comment: spot on for this although as mentioned its a security risk, id rather take the chance of having the password in the script than passing a zip file over the internet unsecured.

you can script it in the following way

zip myarchive.zip /var/www/* -P yourpassword

and it works perfectly.

thank you!

Comment: Great! Now that I know your password is `yourpassword`, all I need to find out is where your computer lives! ;)

Comment: Having the password in a script is one problem, but another, possibly bigger, problem is that while zip is running, everyone on the same machine can see the password in the output of ps -ef

Comment: Just a comment that a zip created with -P fails to extract using MacOSX Finder.  Workaround is to use the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the security features provided by the file system. This is indeed another story, but it does protect your information in most cases.

So I guess doing a `chown` and `chmod` on your archive after creating it will prevent unwanted users from accessing the file, if all you need is a file that can only be read by a certain group. The main advantage is that there's no need to memorize a password here.